# Unable to perform batch update from jdbc template in mariadb

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb

I have piece of code which is working fine with oracle db but giving exception `SQL state [HY000]; error code [1205]; (conn=30) Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: (conn=30) Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction` when trying to execute with mariadb . I have tried multiple solutions i.e. increased innodb_lock_wait_timeout , changed the @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation but still getting the same error . Here is the code which is working fine with orcale but giving exception with mariadb:

```
    public void updateFailureData(final Long mId, final Set<String> errorVals)  {
        try {
            this.jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("UPDATE MARKETS SET ERR_VALS = ? WHERE M_ID = ?", new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                @Override
                public void setValues(final PreparedStatement preparedStatement, final int arg1) throws SQLException {
                    int index = 1;
                    preparedStatement.setString(index++, StringUtils.join(errorVals, ","));
                    preparedStatement.setLong(index, mId);
                }

                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return 1;
                }
            });
        } catch (DataAccessException dataAccessException) {
            System.out.println("Updating errorVals.", dataAccessException);
        }
    }
```

Is there anything which can be done or I am missing ?

Comment: which isolation level are you using in mariadb?

Comment: @RaushanKumar  i updated the isolation level to READ COMMITTED by " SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED"

Comment: still same issue?

Comment: yes the same issue .